# Mongodb - When the data load is more in db i am unable to execute the query

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

```
 $details = $this->mongo_db->select(array('id','token','details'))->where(array('id'=>1))->get('details_table');
```

In my 'details_table' table is 100k data, when i am fetching data based on id query is not executing.

Comment: By your first array you have a single quote

Comment: By mistake single quote added, even then its not working @wolfgang1983